# Plot timeseries chart in Grafana using CSV data source

Tags: csv, grafana, timeserieschart

I am trying to plot a timeseries chart using a csv file in Grafana. But the 'Time' part of it always is a problem. It doesnt let me plot and I dont understand why? There is no error, but just a blank Column.

[image]

Example of the time in csv is like 2018-01-01 00:00:00

The panel title though shows values(if you hover over the grid) but the chart is empty.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out it had to do with the timestamp. Grafana has a default timestamp format of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and my csv had a different format and so, the chart was not rendering.

I modified my dataset accordingly and it started working.

Thank you.